# Horde & IMP username and password?

Tags: linux, horde

I want to know how IMP handles user accounts. Where does it store the username and password for the emailusers?

We have one sql database in Horde but there aren't any usernames or passwords in there. In what file or database does Horde/IMP store the users?

Answer (score 3):

IMP is the Internet Messaging Program. It is written in PHP and provides webmail access to IMAP and POP3 accounts. It has nothing to do with users, it's merely a frontend to an IMAP-server.

You can add or remove users to your IMAP- or POP3-server (Dovecot, Courrier or similar). This is mostly done by adding a new user to the server (`useradd`).

Comment: As a clarification, Horde is typically configured to use the same authentication system as IMP. IMP is typically configured to authenticate by logging into the IMAP server.

Comment: Thanks for answer , How i can find the database of POP3 or IMAP?! Where is the email passwords in server?!

Comment: Mostly they are just users in linux, so you can find them in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: No , i can not find there !\

Comment: What can't you find? The files or the users?